# How to put my recyclerView inside my second fragment?

Tags: android, xml, android-fragments, android-recyclerview

I have Viewpager with tablayout so i want the second TAB2 to be recycler view with images and text i'm trying to do it but always getting nullexception in tab2

```
   String[] names={"Icardi","Candreva","Milito","Perisic","Zanetti"};
String[] positions={"Striker","Winger", "Striker","Winger","Defender"};
int[] images={R.drawable.ic_launcher,R.drawable.ic_launcher,R.drawable.ic_launcher,R.drawable.ic_launcher,R.drawable.ic_launcher,};

TextView textView,textView2;
ImageView imageView;



@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.tab2, container, false);


    RecyclerView rv= (RecyclerView)v.findViewById(R.id.myRecycler);


    rv.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(getActivity()));

    MyAdapter adapter=new MyAdapter(getActivity(),names,positions,images);
    rv.setAdapter(adapter);
        return  v;
}
```

myAdapter

```
public class MyAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<MyHolder>{

Context c;
String[] players;
String[] positions;
int[] images;

public MyAdapter(Context ctx,String[] players,String[] positions,int[] images)
{
    this.c=ctx;
    this.players=players;
    this.positions=positions;
    this.images=images;

}
@Override
public MyHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
    View v= LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.model,null);

    MyHolder holder=new MyHolder(v);

    return holder;
}


@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(MyHolder holder, final int position) {

    holder.nameTxt.setText(players[position]);
    holder.posTxt.setText(positions[position]);
    holder.img.setImageResource(images[position]);

    holder.setItemClickListener(new ItemClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemClick(View v, int pos) {

            Intent i=new Intent(c,MiniDetails.class);

            i.putExtra("Name",players[position]);
            i.putExtra("Position",positions[position]);
            i.putExtra("Image",images[position]);

            c.startActivity(i);

        }
    });

}

@Override
public int getItemCount() {
    return players.length;
}
```

myholder

```
public class MyHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder  implements  View.OnClickListener {

ImageView img;
TextView nameTxt,posTxt;
ItemClickListener itemClickListener;

public MyHolder(View itemView) {
    super(itemView);

    img = (ImageView)itemView.findViewById(R.id.playerImage);
    nameTxt = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.nameTxt);
    posTxt = (TextView)itemView.findViewById(R.id.posTxt);

        itemView.setOnClickListener(this);
}

@Override
public void onClick(View v) {
    this.itemClickListener.onItemClick(v,getLayoutPosition());

}

public  void  setItemClickListener(ItemClickListener ic)
{
    this.itemClickListener=ic;
}
```

listFragment.xml

```
<android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
    android:id="@+id/myRecycler"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    class="android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView "/>
```

model.xml

```
<RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">


    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/playerImage"
        android:padding="10dp"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher"/>

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
        android:text="Name"
        android:id="@+id/nameTxt"
        android:padding="10dp"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/playerImage"/>

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
        android:text="position"
        android:id="@+id/posTxt"
        android:padding="10dp"
        android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/playerImage"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        />


</RelativeLayout>
```

tab2.xml

```
<android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
    android:id="@+id/rv_recycler_view"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" >
</android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView>
```

I'm despered please someone help me ,,,! or guide me.!

logcat

```
FATAL EXCEPTION: main
                                                                       Process: com.example.mike.projectx, PID: 14918
                                                                       java.lang.NullPointerException
                                                                           at com.example.mike.projectx.FirstTabs.Tab2.onCreateView(Tab2.java:45)
                                                                           at android.support.v4.app.Fragment.performCreateView(Fragment.java:2087)
                                                                           at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1113)
                                                                           at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1295)
                                                                           at android.support.v4.app.BackStackRecord.run(BackStackRecord.java:801)
                                                                           at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.execSingleAction(FragmentManager.java:1643)
                                                                           at android.support.v4.app.BackStackRecord.commitNowAllowingStateLoss(BackStackRecord.java:679)
                                                                           at android.support.v4.app.FragmentStatePagerAdapter.finishUpdate(FragmentStatePagerAdapter.java:166)
                                                                           at android.support.v4.view.ViewPager.populate(ViewPager.java:1272)
                                                                           at android.support.v4.view.ViewPager.populate(ViewPager.java:1120)
                                                                           at android.support.v4.view.ViewPager.onMeasure(ViewPager.java:1646)
                                                                           at android.view.View.measure(View.java:16518)
                                                                           at android.widget.RelativeLayout.measureChildHorizontal(RelativeLayout.java:719)
                                                                           at android.widget.RelativeLayout.onMeasure(RelativeLayout.java:455)
                                                                           at android.view.View.measure(View.java:16518)
                                                                           at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:5125)
                                                                           at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:310)
                                                                           at android.support.v7.widget.ContentFrameLayout.onMeasure(ContentFrameLayout.java:139)
                                                                           at android.view.View.measure(View.java:16518)
                                                                           at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:5125)
                                                                           at android.support.v7.widget.ActionBarOverlayLayout.onMeasure(ActionBarOverlayLayout.java:393)
                                                                           at android.view.View.measure(View.java:16518)
                                                                           at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:5125)
                                                                           at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:310)
                                                                           at android.view.View.measure(View.java:16518)
                                                                           at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:5125)
                                                                           at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureChildBeforeLayout(LinearLayout.java:1404)
                                                                           at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureVertical(LinearLayout.java:695)
                                                                           at android.widget.LinearLayout.onMeasure(LinearLayout.java:588)
                                                                           at android.view.View.measure(View.java:16518)
                                                                           at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:5125)
                                                                           at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:310)
                                                                           at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView.onMeasure(PhoneWindow.java:2410)
                                                                           at android.view.View.measure(View.java:16518)
                                                                           at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performMeasure(ViewRootImpl.java:1921)
                                                                           at android.view.ViewRootImpl.measureHierarchy(ViewRootImpl.java:1114)
                                                                           at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performTraversals(ViewRootImpl.java:1296)
                                                                           at android.view.ViewRootImpl.doTraversal(ViewRootImpl.java:1001)
                                                                           at android.view.ViewRootImpl$TraversalRunnable.run(ViewRootImpl.java:5680)
                                                                           at android.view.Choreographer$CallbackRecord.run(Choreographer.java:761)
                                                                           at android.view.Choreographer.doCallbacks(Choreographer.java:574)
                                                                           at android.view.Choreographer.doFrame(Choreographer.java:544)
                                                                           at android.view.Choreographer$FrameDisplayEventReceiver.run(Choreographer.java:747)
                                                                           at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:733)
                                                                           at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
                                                                           at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
                                                                           at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5001)
                                                                           at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
                                                                           at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
                                                                           at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:801)
                                                                           at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:617)
                                                                           at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Comment: please post your logcat error here ...

Comment: In tab2.xml file, `TextView` and `ImageView` is not available. Remove this two lines and check it. `textView = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.nameTxt);
    imageView = (ImageView) v.findViewById(R.id.playerImage);`

Comment: i did try it and check the logcat same error

Comment: `textView2 = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.posTxt);
    textView = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.nameTxt);
    imageView = (ImageView) v.findViewById(R.id.playerImage);`

These lines should be removed as they are a part of the `recycler view`

Comment: I remove it same problem check the log cat when i click on tab2 in logcar goes to the      rv.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(getActivity()));

Comment: @Piyush my problem is not how to understand null exception its how put recyclerview inside fragment :@

Comment: findViewById in onActivityCreated() method, not in onCreateView() in your fragment....